# How to include and use new fonts in wxWidgets projet?

Tags: wxwidgets

How to include and use new fonts in wxWidgets projet?
I am using VS2005.
I just want to print text using new ttf font.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: And how can I larger the font?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're willing to link against something like FreeType:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType

...most any program is going to require the font to be installed to the operating system, by the user or by some OS-specific script.  You can't just load it by filename off the cuff in your app.

Because of the platform dependence of naming and accessing custom fonts, the path of least resistance is not to try and hardcode a font...but to let the user pick one out of a dialog.  You would use a `wxFontDialog` for this:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfontdialog.html

It will let you retrieve the `wxFontData`, from which you can get the chosen `wxFont`:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfontdata.html#wxfontdatagetchosenfont

Once you have that, you can save and reload an identity of the font via the native string interface:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfont.html#wxfontgetnativefontinfodesc

Trying to formulate these strings on your own or work with the "face name" is a little dodgier:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfont.html#wxfontsetfacename

Generally speaking a lot of the same problems arise here as dealing with fonts in HTML.  If you have a very specific idea about the cross-platform appearance of some text, your best bet is often to make an image out of that text and use that instead of going through the hoops to get the font you want in the app.  If you're more flexible and have a lot of text the user is interested in, then they may be interested in changing the font too.  So just use a default but offer the user a choice to pick anything they want which is installed on their system.

*(Note: I personally consider the handling of fonts in pretty much every OS or document system to be a disgrace.  Imagine a world where in order to get a graphic to display in your program you had to register it with the operating system through a complex process and it would not copy from machine to machine when you copied a document in which it was embedded.  We're dealing now with graphics that are orders of magnitude larger than font files, and yet they are handled seamlessly while people seem to accept the lack of seamless font transfer as "normal".  Archaic DRM mindsets of font vendors is one side of the problem, but lame technology is another big component.)*

Comment: I agree to most of your words.. Thanks ...but I have find a way to do that without installing it on the particular OS.

Comment: Then you'll need Freetype or similar.  It's cross-platform:   http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html